# Downloading and replacing file only if target is newer than source

Tags: linux, download, wget

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

User uploads **file1.jpg** to **Server A**

Using wget **Server B** only downloads **file1.jpg** from **Server A** if the file is newer than the one that already exists on **Server B** and then replaces the file on **Server B** with the new one.

I know I can use:

```
 wget -N http://www.mywebsite.com/files/file1.jpg
```

To check that the target file is newer than the source but I'm a little confused as to how I format the command to let it know what and where the actual source file is?

Is it something like:

```
 wget -N http://www.mywebsite.com/files/file1.jpg /serverb/files/file1.jpg
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to (re)download file with wget only when the file is newer or the size changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77050692/how-to-redownload-file-with-wget-only-when-the-file-is-newer-or-the-size-chang)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `-P` option to specify the directory where the file(s) will be downloaded:

```
$ wget -N -P /serverb/files/ http://www.mywebsite.com/files/file1.jpg
```

You are also talking about downloading and replacing the file. Be aware, that `wget` overwrites the file, so it is "broken" while being downloaded. I don't think you can do atomic replacement of the file using only `wget`. You need a small script that uses temporary files and `move` to atomically replace the file in Server B.

Comment: Thanks Erika, I should have been more concise in my question though. I'm trying to run this command in a shell script and nothing I try (including your answer) is working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you get any output or error messages from wget or from shell when executing the shell script?

Comment: where would I see those? Sorry, bit of a shell noobie here ;)

Comment: How are you executing your shell script?

Comment: via a cron job, being executed every minute, just while trying to get it to work

Comment: Try `wget -o /tmp/wget.log -N -P /serverb/files/ http://www.mywebsite.com/files/file1.jpg` to log the output of wget to /tmp/wget.log.

Comment: No errors being reported, it's just not downloading the file?

Comment: Should there be anything in the error log? It's not even creating the error log file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58790/discussion-between-grant-and-erki-a).